# Elasticsearch aggregation performance takes a hit on relatively small dataset

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a cluster of 3 Linux VMs (each machine has 2 cores, 8GB of RAM per core) where we have deployed an Elasticsearch 2.1.1 cluster, with default configuration. Store size is ~50GB for ~3M documents -so arguably fairly modest. We index documents ranging in size from tweets to blog posts. For each document, we extract "entities" (eg, if string "Barack Obama" appears in a document, we locate its character position and classify it into an entity type, in this case the type "person", or "statesman") from the text before indexing the document alongside its array of extracted entities.

Our mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": { "enabled": "false" },
            "dynamic": false
        },
        "document": {
            "properties": {
                "body": { "type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "english" },
                "timestamp": { "type": "date", "index":"not_analyzed" },
                "author": {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                    }
                },
                "entities": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "include_in_parent": true,
                    "properties": {
                        "text": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                        "type": { "type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "path" },
                        "start": { "type": "integer", "index":"not_analyzed", "doc_values": false },
                        "stop": { "type": "integer", "index":"not_analyzed", "doc_values": false }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Path analyzer is used on the entity type field (entity types are based on some hierarchical taxonomy, so the type is represented as a path-like string). The only other analyzed field is the body of the document. For some reason that I could expand on if necessary, we have to index the entities as nested types, though we are still including them in the parent document.

There are on average ~10 entities extracted per document, so ~30M entities in total. The cardinality for the entities field is thus fairly high (~2M unique values).

Our problem is that some of the aggregations we are doing are very slow (>30s). In particular, the following two aggregations:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "query": {
                    // Some query
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                // Some filter
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "aggData": {
            terms: { field: 'entities.text', size: 50 }
        }
    }
}
```

And the same one, just replacing 'terms' aggregation with 'significant_terms':

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "query": {
                    // Some query
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                // Some filter
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "aggData": {
            significant_terms: { field: 'entities.text', size: 50 }
        }
    }
}
```

My questions:

- Why are these aggregations prohibitively slow?
- Is there something stupid/inefficient in the mapping strategy?
- Does indexing the entities as a nested document while still keeping them in the parent document have an impact?
- Is it simply that the cardinality of the entities field is just too big and Elasticsearch is not magic?

Comment: What's the server stats during the 30s query? CPU/Heap/Memory usage? Maybe try installing Marvel to see if it gives you any hints. Another suggestion is to try and map the `entities.text` field with [`doc_values: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html) and reindexing the data.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having lots of issues installing Marvel for ES 2. A combination of proxy problems, firewall and having to go through a Windows box and the install process on Windows being messed up... I'll keep trying because I understand this would give valuable data to better understand the problem. In the meantime, I will try your suggestion of using `doc_values: true`

Comment: Actually, I think that, in ES 2, `doc_values` is set to true by default for all fields except analyzed string fields (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html): "Starting in version 2.0, doc values became the default format for almost all field types, with the notable exception of analyzed string fields")